# Dynamically creating a new instance in Java

Tags: java, constructor

I have a class called `CD` with the following private variables:

```
private String artist = "";
private String year = "";
private String albumName = "";
private ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This class is used to store input data that is in this format:

```
Led Zeppelin
1979 In Through the Outdoor
-In the Evening
-South Bound Saurez
-Fool in the Rain
-Hot Dog
-Carouselambra
-All My Love
-I'm Gonna Crawl
```

I have a `CDParser` class that is in charge of parsing the file called `sample.db` line by line to store it into our `CD` object. After parsing, the `CD` object, after initializing it with `CD newCD = new CD()` has the following structure:

```
artist = "Led Zeppelin"

year = "1979"

albumName = "In Through the Outdoor"

songs = {"-In the Evening", "-South Bound Saurez", "-Fool in the Rain", "-Hot Dog"}
```

Now.. For this project, `sample.db` contains many albums, which looks like the following:

```
Led Zeppelin
1979 In Through the Outdoor
-In the Evening
-South Bound Saurez
-Fool in the Rain
-Hot Dog
-Carouselambra
-All My Love
-I'm Gonna Crawl

Led Zeppelin
1969 II
-Whole Lotta Love
-What Is and What Should Never Be
-The Lemon Song
-Thank You
-Heartbreaker
-Living Loving Maid (She's Just a Woman)
-Ramble On
-Moby Dick
-Bring It on Home

Bob Dylan
1966 Blonde on Blonde
-Rainy Day Women #12 & 35
-Pledging My Time
-Visions of Johanna
-One of Us Must Know (Sooner or Later)
-I Want You
-Stuck Inside of Mobile with the Memphis Blues Again
-Leopard-Skin Pill-Box Hat
-Just Like a Woman
-Most Likely You Go Your Way (And I'll Go Mine)
-Temporary Like Achilles
-Absolutely Sweet Marie
-4th Time Around
-Obviously 5 Believers
-Sad Eyed Lady of the Lowlands
```

I have so far been able to parse all three different albums and save them into my `CD` object, but ran into a roadblock where I'm simply saving all three albums into the same `newCD` object.

My question is - is there a way of programmatically initialize my `CD` constructor that will follow the format `newCD1`, `newCD2`, `newCD3`, etc, as I parse the `sample.db`?

What this means is, as I parse this particular file:

1. `newCD1` would be the album `In Through the Outdoor` (and its respective private vars)
2. `newCD2` would be the album `II` (and its respective private vars)
3. `newCD3` would be the album `Blonde on Blonde`, and so on

Is this a smart way to do it? Or could you suggest me a better way?

EDIT:

Attached is my parser code. `ourDB` is an `ArrayList` containing every line of `sample.db`:

```
    CD newCD = new CD();

    int line = 0;

    for(String string : this.ourDB) {
        if(line == ARTIST) {
            newCD.setArtist(string);
            System.out.println(string);
            line++;
        } else if(line == YEAR_AND_ALBUM_NAME){
            String[] elements = string.split(" ");

            String[] albumNameArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(elements, 1, elements.length);

            String year = elements[0];
            String albumName = join(albumNameArr, " ");

            newCD.setYear(year);
            newCD.setAlbumName(albumName);

            System.out.println(year);
            System.out.println(albumName);

            line++;
        } else if(line >= SONGS && !string.equals("")) {
            newCD.setSong(string);
            System.out.println(string);
            line++;
        } else if(string.isEmpty()){
            line = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: its not clear what you  are trying to do. also if possible add current code snippet

Comment: Seems like you not looping correctly between objects. Show us more code you have.

Comment: Are you looking for arrays and lists?

Comment: I would steer you away from trying to do this through constructors. Instead, just use a POJO in which you can add more albums & songs as needed

Comment: You already have a `List` inside your CD class that you are using. Use one _outside_ too, to store your CDs. Otherwise use a `Map` to index the CDs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a single `CD` object, so you keep overwriting it. Instead, You could hold a collection of `CD`s. E.g.:

```
List<CD> cds = new ArrayList<>();

CD newCD = new CD();
int line = 0;

for(String string : this.ourDB) {
    if(line == ARTIST) {
        newCD.setArtist(string);
        System.out.println(string);
        line++;
    } else if(line == YEAR_AND_ALBUM_NAME){
        String[] elements = string.split(" ");

        String[] albumNameArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(elements, 1, elements.length);

        String year = elements[0];
        String albumName = join(albumNameArr, " ");

        newCD.setYear(year);
        newCD.setAlbumName(albumName);

        System.out.println(year);
        System.out.println(albumName);

        line++;
    } else if(line >= SONGS && !string.equals("")) {
        newCD.setSong(string);
        System.out.println(string);
        line++;
    } else if(string.isEmpty()){
        // We're starting a new CD!
        // Add the one we have so far to the list, and start afresh
        cds.add(newCD);
        newCD = new CD();
        line = 0;
    }
}

// Take care of the case the file doesn't end with a newline:
if (line != 0) {
    cds.add(newCD);
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I mean!

Comment: Ah.. My source of confusion came from the fact that I thought each instance I store within my collection needs to have a different name, i.e. if I have a `newCD` within my list of `newCD`s, the next instance must not contain the same name.

Comment: Hi Mureinik. With this, I am running into the problem where I am only printing out the first two albums - the third album seems to be missing. I went ahead to added print statements within each if statement before the final else-if, and I was getting the correct outputs, but if I try my `CD` object at the `string.isEmpty()` if-statement, I only get two CD objects.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage I assumed, for some reason, you'd have an empty line at the end of the file. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're using the same object reference of `CD` to fill the values of the parse of the file.

Just make sure to initialize and store every instance of `CD newCD` every time you start parsing the content of a new album.

You may do the following:

```
List<CD> cdList = new ArrayList<>();
for (<some way to handle you're reading a new album entry from your file>) {
    CD cd = new CD();
    //method below parses the data in the db per album entry
    //an album entry may contain several lines
    parseData(cd, this.ourDB);
    cdList.add(cd);
}
System.out.println(cdList);
```

Your current way to parse the file works but is not as readable as it should be. I would recommend using two loops:

```
List<CD> cdList = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<String> yourDBIterator = this.ourDB.iterator();
//it will force to enter the first time
while (yourDBIterator.hasNext()) {
    //do the parsing here...
    CD cd = new CD();
    //method below parses the data in the db per album entry
    //an album entry may contain several lines
    parseData(cd, yourDBIterator);
    cdList.add(cd);
}

//...
public void parseData(CD cd, Iterator<String> it) {
    String string = it.next();
    int line = ARTIST;
    while (!"".equals(string)) {
        if (line == ARTIST) {
            newCD.setArtist(string);
            System.out.println(string);
            line++;
        } else if(line == YEAR_AND_ALBUM_NAME){
            String[] elements = string.split(" ");
            String[] albumNameArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(elements, 1, elements.length);
            String year = elements[0];
            String albumName = join(albumNameArr, " ");
            newCD.setYear(year);
            newCD.setAlbumName(albumName);
            System.out.println(year);
            System.out.println(albumName);
            line++;
        } else if(line >= SONGS && !string.equals("")) {
            newCD.setSong(string);
            System.out.println(string);
            line++;
        }
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            string = it.next();
        } else {
            string = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Then, your code

Comment: I am indeed using the same instance of the `CD` class. Which is my question - how do I dynamically generate a new instance to store each album?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage just do `CD newCD = new CD();` properly.

Comment: Thank you - this is precisely what I meant

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the Builder design pattern to construct the CD object. If you read lines always in the same order, it will be not complicated to implement and use. Good tutorial: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/the-builder-pattern-in-practice.html